# In, Cypress Automation the cities list/names are not loading in autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automation, mocha.js, cypress

It's a react app,I have also added delays in pressing keys & waits for loading but nothing is working .[image: Image is attached here]

```
cy.get('input[placeholder="Address"]').invoke('show').type("San Diego", { 
    delay: 1000 });
    cy.get('.suggestion-item').invoke('show');
    cy.wait(3000)
```

Comment: If you have no solution please don't down-vote

Answer (score 3):

you can use `children()`

```
cy.get('.suggestion-item').children().contains('San Diego').click()
```

You can also view more in detail [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children.html#Syntax)

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: <input id="search-location" aria-label="search location" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="Address" class="location-search-input" value="San Diego"><div class="autocomplete-dropdown-container"><div class="suggestion-item" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Loading...</div></div>

Comment: Hope this one works for you:

    cy.get('search-location).type('San Diego')
    cy.get('.suggestion-item').should('be.hidden').invoke('show')